# Is there a difference between "21 час" and "21 часа"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Based on what I've seen so far, the case should follow the last number, 21 (one - один) should be nom. sing. but when I was looking at the macbook pro on apple's web site, they describe the battery time in hours like this:

> До **21 часа** при воспроизведении фильмов из приложения Apple TV
> До 14 часов работы в интернете по беспроводной сети

[Apple's example page](https://www.apple.com/ru/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/)

So my question is: shouldn't be "21 час" instead of "21 часа"? Or is there some other rule about numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preposition **до** governs the Genitive, and **два́дцать оди́н час** in the Genitive becomes **двадцати́ одного́ ча́са**.

Not to be confused with **часа́** as in **24 часа́** (Nominative):

| Nom. | два́дцать | оди́н час | четы́ре часа́ | пять часо́в |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gen. | двадцати́ | одного́ ча́са | четырёх часо́в | пяти́ часо́в |
| Dat. | двадцати́ | одному́ ча́су | четырём часа́м | пяти́ часа́м |
| Acc. | два́дцать | оди́н час | четы́ре часа́ | пять часо́в |
| Ins. | двадцатью́ | одни́м ча́сом | четырьмя́ часа́ми | пятью́ часа́ми |
| Loc. | двадцати́ | одно́м ча́се (часу́) | четырёх часа́х | пяти́ часа́х |

Answer (score 1):

Preposition **до** in this meaning (**up to 21 hours**, can be less, but can't be more, because 21 shows **maximum or limit**) requires **genitive** case.

Up to — до двадцати одного часа.